# Facing Issue in passing value to child components

Tags: lightning-aura-components

In the child component "item.label" isnt showing any values and also checkbox item.ischecked also not working properly.
Please help me to ressolve the issue

```
public class S360_ListingsFilterController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<String> getPicklistValues(String objectAPI,string fieldName){

        Map<string,String> mapReturn = new Map<string,String>();

        Schema.SObjectType targetType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectAPI);
        Sobject Object_name  = targetType.newSObject();
        Schema.sObjectType sobject_type = Object_name.getSObjectType(); //grab the sobject that was passed
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sobject_describe = sobject_type.getDescribe(); //describe the sobject
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldmap = sobject_describe.fields.getMap();

        List<Schema.SObjectField> fieldNames = new List<Schema.SObjectField>();

        // for (String fieldName : fieldMap.keySet()){
        list<string> options=new List<string>();
        List <string> options1 = new List<string>();
        Schema.DisplayType fielddataType = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getType();

        if(fielddataType == Schema.DisplayType.Picklist ||fielddataType == Schema.DisplayType.MultiPicklist) {
            List<Schema.PicklistEntry> pick_list_values = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getPickListValues(); 
            String str = String.valueOf(fieldMap.get(fieldName));
            String values='';
            for (Schema.PicklistEntry a : pick_list_values) { 
                values = values + a.getValue()+'|'+a.getLabel()+',';
                options1.add(a.getValue()+'|'+a.getLabel());  //It contains value and name label
                options.add(a.getLabel());//Here added only Label to the List
            }

            values = values.subString(0,values.length()-1);

            //mapReturn.put(str,options1);
            mapReturn.put(str,values);

        }
        // }
        System.debug('mapReturn'+mapReturn);
        return options;
    }
}
```

---

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="S360_ListingsFilterController">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="AppTable" type="List"/>


    <c:S360_MultiSelectCheckboxComponent CompId="{!v.filterCategoryId}" picklistValues="{!v.AppTable}" FieldName="Categories__c" GroupLabel="Category"/>
</aura:component>
```

---

```
child component:

<aura:component controller="PicklistDescriber">
    <aura:attribute name="CompId" type="string" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="GroupLabel" type="string" default=""/>

    <aura:attribute name="Items" type="Object[]" default="[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="DefaultK" type="string" default="All"/>
    <aura:attribute name="DefaultValue" type="Object[]" default="[]" description="private attribute"/>
    <aura:attribute name="picklistKV" type="Object[]" default="[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="picklistValues" type="Object[]" default="[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="SObjectName" type="string" default=""/>

        <div class="slds-form-element__control">   //problem is here
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.picklistValues}" var="item">
                <p> item value:{!item}</p>
                <c:S360_CheckboxInline CompId="{!v.CompId+'#'+item.label}" InputLabel="{!item.label}" IsChecked="{!item.isChecked}" IsDisabled="{!v.IsDisabled}"/>
            </aura:iteration>
        </div>

    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: try by replacing {!item.label} with {!v.item.label} and {!item.isChecked}
 with {!v.item.isChecked}..

Comment: Does this line `<p> item value:{!item}</p>` show anything?

Comment: Instead of passing the values separately, I would recommend passing it as a single Object and process it in the child in your way..